# Classes and Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am experimenting with simple Hello World apps in Google App Engine. I wanted to create a separate class which I would import in the main.py and use.

main.py:

```
import helloWorld

helloWorld.hi()
```

helloWorld.py:

```
class helloWorld():
    def hi():
        print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
        print ''
        print 'Hello, world!'
```

What is the solution to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```
from helloWorld import helloWorld
helloWorld().hi()
```

or :

```
import helloWorld
helloWorld.helloWorld().hi()
```

The first one only imports the class `helloWorld` from the module `helloWorld` and you can directly use it by its name.

In the second one we imported everything from the module `helloWorld` but we can access it using `helloWorld.attr` syntax only.

[Docs on modules](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).

And the method `hi` of class `helloWorld` must contain an argument `self`.

```
def hi(self):
```

Comment: I assume this is what he actually wanted :) although his class method signature is wrong :/

Comment: Thanks...I think the central issue I'm having is with the yaml file. For some reason I can't get GAE to upload my other scripts correctly, it is giving a 500 error whenever I try to import an external class...

Comment: @JumBopap I've not used GAE, so can't say much about that.